# Regex - Value after = until ;

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to create the Regex on my own but I couldn't do it. So I'm hoping for some help. I get a string like this:

```
test=foo;test1=bar;test2=;test3= .some.other.stuff
```

My regex for findind the values after the "="

```
(?<=@test=).+?(?=;)
```

It only works with

1. @test=
2. test1= (and only if it has a value after the =)

Can somebody help me? I just always need the value after the "=" and if there is no value I need an "empty match".

What is even more tricky is the end of the string because it doesn't have the ";" anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless performance is huge concern for that parsing code - `Split` would produce more readable code:

```
 var pairs = text
   .Split(';')
   .Select(v => v.Split('='))
   .Select(pair=> new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pair[0], pair.Length==2? pair[1]:""));
```

Regex version could look like following:

```
Regex.Matches("test=foo;test1=bar;test2=;test3= .some.other.stuff",
   "([^=]+)=([^;]*)(?:;*)");
```

main part - specify last `;` character as "optional non captured group" - `(?:;*)`.

Comment: I had it as a split operation at first but I want it to be as performant as possible. Usually I do everything with string Operations like split, replace, substring and remove but for this task I wanted to use regex because I receive this string (with different values) really often in a short period of time and I need to process them as fast as possible.

Comment: @Shamshiel `IndexOf`/`Substring` would likely be better from performance point of view - correctly hand written state machine for particular case will beat the same one generated by Regex. As any performance exercise this assumes you either doing it strictly for fun/education OR really measured code and found that this particular piece is main bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I always thought that RegEx is faster than string operations.

Comment: @Shamshiel Regex is not magic - the end result is the same set of strings you'd get with any other method. What regex give you is standard way to express complex searches and provide good performance to perform the searches - using all know optimizations. As result they frequently outperform basic string manipulation code, but you can always write at least as good manual variant - i.e. pick the same optimizations and you get the same perf.

Answer (score 1):

To get just the values:

```regex
[^;]+=(?<val>[^;]*)
```

will output

```
val: foo
val: bar
val: 
val:  .some.other.stuff
```

(Yes, there is still a match on the empty one, but the string is `""`). You could eliminate that match with a `+` instead of a `*` in the pattern.

A more complete approach that gives you the keys and values is

```regex
(?<key>[^;])+=(?<val>[^;]*)
```

which outputs

```
key: t
val: foo
key: 1
val: bar
key: 2
val: 
key: 3
val:  .some.other.stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply do something like this (no LINQ here):

```
string yourString = @"test=foo;test1=bar;test2=;test3=someotherstuff";
string[] temp = yourString.Split(';');

Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i += 2) 
{
   var temp2 = temp[i].Split('=');
   values.Add(temp2[0], temp2[1]);
}
```